# How can i resolve my update record query in same page?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-5, eloquent

---

In My list view I have all the details of department. But when I click on details It will display me a Pop-up. In Pop up box it has to fetch and give me all the details of particular field but instead of that it always give me details of last inserted record

Here is my code of blade file

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<section>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row page-titles">
                <div class="col-md-5 align-self-center">
                    <h4 class="text-themecolor">{{__('Department')}}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-info text-white">+ Add Department</a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Department </h4>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{route('store_department')}}">
                                        @csrf
                                        <div class="form-group">

                                        @if(Session::has('key'))
                                            <?php $createdBy = Session::get('key')['username']; ?>
                                        @endif

                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="createdBy" value="<?php echo $createdBy ?>">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameOfDepartment" placeholder="Add New Department">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="table-responsive m-t-40">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped ">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Department Name</th>
                                        <th>Created By</th>
                                        <th>Created On</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @if($listOfDepartment != null)
                                    @foreach($listOfDepartment as $departmentList)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$departmentList->createdBy}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$departmentList->created_at}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="{{route('edit_department', $departmentList->id)}}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEditModal"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" style="color:#0066ff" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                                <a href="{{route('delete_department', $departmentList->id)}}"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" style="color:red" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div id="myEditModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabelEdit" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabelEdit">Edit Department</h4>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('update_department', $departmentList->id) }}">
                                @csrf
                                @method('PUT')
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                             <input type="text" name="nameOfDepartment" class="form-control" placeholder="Edit Department" value="{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</section>
@endsection
```

here is my code of department controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Department;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DepartmentController extends Controller
{
    public function createDepartment()
    {
        return view('pages.department');
    }

    public function storeDepartment(Request $request)
    {
        $department = new Department();
        $department->createdBy = $request->get('createdBy');
        $department->nameOfDepartment = $request->get('nameOfDepartment');
        $department->save();

        return redirect('list-department')->with('Success', 'Department Added Successfully!');
    }

    public function listDepartment()
    {
        $listOfDepartment = Department::all();
        return view('pages.department', compact('listOfDepartment'));
    }

    public function editDepartment($id)
    {
        $departments = Department::find($id);
        return view('pages.department', compact('departments', 'id'));
    }

    public function updateDepartment(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $department = Department::find($id);
        $department->createdby = $request->get('createdBy');
        $department->nameOfDepartment = $request->get('nameOfDepartment');
        $department->save();

        return redirect('list-department')->with('Success', 'Department Updated Successfully!');
    }

    public function deleteDepartment($id)
    {
        $department = Department::find($id);
        $department->delete();

        return redirect('list-department')->with('Success', 'Department Deleted SuccessFully!');
    }
}
```

And Here Are My Routes

```
Route::get('add-department', 'DepartmentController@createDepartment')->name('create_department');
Route::post('store-department', 'DepartmentController@storeDepartment')->name('store_department');
Route::get('list-department', 'DepartmentController@listDepartment')->name('list_department');
Route::get('edit-department/{id}', 'DepartmentController@editDepartment')->name('edit_department');
Route::put('update-department/{id}', 'DepartmentController@updateDepartment')->name('update_department');
Route::get('delete-department/{id}', 'DepartmentController@deleteDepartment')->name('delete_department');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modal is always created with the last `$departmentList`

You are using this to create some kind of list

```php
@foreach($listOfDepartment as $departmentList)                                      
<tr>                                        
    <td>{{$departmentList->nameOfDepartment}}</td>                           
    <td>{{$departmentList->createdBy}}</td>
    <td>{{$departmentList->created_at}}</td>
    <td>                                    
        <a href="{{route('edit_department', $departmentList->id)}}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEditModal">
            <i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" style="color:#0066ff" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>                                            
        <a href="{{route('delete_department', $departmentList->id)}}">
            <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" style="color:red" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

You end the loop here so `$departmentList` is the last one from the loop

Later you add some html again that uses `$departmentList`

```php
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('update_department', $departmentList->id) }}">
```

This variable still contains the last department from your loop before.

You can probably utilize some javascript that opens the modal and put the correct post url in place.

Comment: Will you please explain more?
I don't understand much

Comment: What part do you need more information about ? @John_rees

Comment: How can I use javascript?
Can you suggest some line of code??

Comment: Javascript is just an exampe of doing this client side. There are many other solutions. Can you update your code so i can see what you have tried ?

Comment: I had sent all code of my department's blade & controller file, and routes too

Comment: Whats the missing tell me so i sent it

Comment: @John_rees Yes and i pointed out where the issue was and gave you a direction to continue. I am not going to make the code for you as i don't know the scope and requirements. even if i did i would not do it. i am willing to assist on any problems you face but i am not gonna make the project for you.